# Cannot reinstall Ubuntu, only get error messages

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm trying to reinstall Ubuntu. I have a dual boot Ubuntu/Windows setup. Ubuntu was installing system updates, and then we had a power shortage. When I tried to relaunch Ubuntu, I just got a bunch of error messages. I decided I wanted to upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04, but to do a clean install. But every time I try to install Ubuntu from my USB, this pops up on my screen.

[image]

Comment: The specific `nouveau` version included seems not to like your graphics card. You need to use `nomodeset`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've gathered from your question, the errors are most likely due to the power shortage you faced. These messages indicate that there are BIOS errors related to power management control due to an improper ACPI table. The purpose of ACPI is to control the hardware resources and power management. The ACPI checks and improves upon existing power and configuration standards for hardware devices. However, once power 
management is under the control of the operating system, it takes over and has exclusive control of all aspects of power management and device configuration. The OS then usually emulates ACPI compatible system calls, but does not use the BIOS for that. You can try to:

1. Upgrade BIOS version
2. Override DSDT/SSDT(very dangerous)

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface
https://access.redhat.com/articles/65378

Comment: My moterboard is an MSI MS-7751. They have a live update service included, but when I try to update the BIOS, it says this:
>Start LiveUpdate, please wait...
error: cannot read the Linux header
error: you need to load the kernel first.